# Python Import my_module.py and all the packages my module is dependent on show up also

Tags: python, module, ipython

I have been working to create my own module, with a collection of functions within this module.  The various functions are dependent on a couple of other packages, including `pandas`, `networkx`, `time`, among others.  I also currently have a blank `__init__.py` file stored in the same location in my python path where my module is stored.

After importing `my_module.py` and I want to call one of my specific functions within `my_module.py`, I like to use TAB to show the different functions within `my_module`.  However, when I do this, I also see `my_module.pandas`, `my_module.networkx`, `my_module.time`...

I would like to make it so that the dependent modules like `pandas`, `networkx`, and `time` do not show up as options when I'm looking at the functions within `my_module.[function_name]`.

I believe I need to add something to my `__init.py__` file, but I'm not sure exactly what I need to add.

***Example***

*Currently, I have to following files in my python_modules folder:*

```
__init__.py # blank file
my_module.py
```

*my_module.py contains the following functions:*

```
import networkx
import pandas
import time

def load_data(in_file):
    data = pandas.read_csv(in_file)
    return data

def load_network(in_file):
    g = networkx.read_edgelist(in_file, delimiter=',')
    return g

etc...
```

*After I import my_module.py and I want to call a specific function within my_module.py:*

```
my_module.
time    networkx    pandas    load_data    load_network
```

*However, I want only what my actual functions to be listed as options, and not the dependent packages my_module.py is reliant on.*

```
my_module.
load_data    load_network
```

**edit:  I am using IPython**

Comment: Are you trying to fool the tab completion in the standard python interpreter, in IPython, or in some IDE?

Comment: The reason I ask is that, IIRC, by default IPython will only complete exported names (meaning names in `__all__` if it's present, names not starting with `_` if no `__all__` is present), but the standard interpreter will complete everything, even things like `__cached__` and `__doc__`.

Comment: Or, instead of answering that question and waiting for more info, change your code to `import pandas as _pandas` (and, if necessary search&replace in your module), then see whether your favorite interpreter offers `_pandas` or not, which should tell you whether this is a relevant tack.

Comment: In that case, I'm pretty sure either creating an `__all__` in your module, or doing `import pandas as _pandas`, will do what you want, without having to go to a horrible hacky alternative (like, e.g., copying the globals you need out of `pandas` and then doing `del pandas`, or `import`ing into a class or function or other sub-namespace, etc.). But please try them and let me know before I search for docs to back that up and write it up as an answer…